# Symfony 4 - Multi assert difficults

Tags: symfony, validation, constraints, assert

in my symfony project I have an entity that has this field:

```
/**
 * Solde
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
 */
private $solde;
```

This field can be either null, equal to 0 or greater than 0 but can not be negative.

So I wonder how I can organize the asserts for this field?

Can I do something like this?

```
 /**
 * @Assert\!Negative
 */
```

Otherwise the asserts I should use would be:

```
/ ** 
 * @Assert \ Null () 
 * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(0)
 * /
```

But if I use both, it may be a problem because one must make sure that the value is zero, and the other must verify that it is positive or equal to 0

Comment: Just using `GreaterThanOrEqual(0)` looks like it fits best from what I understand. `!Negative` is not possible. If you really want to have your own specific constraint, so that you only need one, you can write a custom constraint. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: Null only specifically checks for `null`, not zero. By default `GreaterThanOrEqual(0)` will also allow `null`. You can see this in the [Test](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Tests/Constraints/GreaterThanOrEqualValidatorTest.php#L54). `@Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(1)` will pass when the input value `null` is given

Comment: Yes, I did PositivOrZero, is it the same thing ? It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Symfony 4.3+ you can use [PositiveOrZero](https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/reference/constraints/PositiveOrZero.html):

```
/**
 * @Assert\PositiveOrZero
 */
```

If you combine this with `nullable=true`, all positive numbers, `0` and `null` will be valid.

For older versions of Symfony you can use:

```
/**
 * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(0)
 */
```

Again with `nullable=true` and you will have the same effect.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

or you can create your own validator with its set of logic
[enter link description here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html)